# Is there a way to build multiple targets on the same gradle build script on iOS?

Tags: ios, gradle

#### I am using Gradle XCODE plugin and I am able to build a single target but I am wondering whether I can build all my targets at once?

My current Script: (Which works fine for single target)

```
buildscript 
{ 
    repositories 
    { 
        maven 
        { 
            url('http://openbakery.org/repository/') 
        } 
        mavenCentral() 
    } 
    dependencies 
    {
        classpath group: 'org.openbakery', name: 'xcodePlugin', version: '0.9.2' 
    } 
} 
apply plugin: 'Xcode' 
xcodebuild 
{ 
    scheme = 'TestBuildGradle' 
    configuration = 'Debug' 
    sdk = 'iphonesimulator7.0' 
    target = 'TestBuildGradle' 
    unitTestTarget = 'TestBuildGradleTests' 
    destination 
    { 
        platform = 'iOS Simulator' 
        name = 'iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)' 
        os='7.0' 
    } 
}
```

I am looking at some options like

`target = "allTargets"` or

`target = ['Target1', 'Target2', 'Target3', .....]`

Comment: After watching presentation - it looks like it is not possible. The author is using different build files for building different applications. Check my answer

Answer (score 3):

Not positive this is what you need, but here goes:

If you do a gradle tasks at the command line the xcodebuild tasks are:

```
Xcode tasks
-----------
archive - Prepare the app bundle that it can be archive
build - Builds the Xcode project
clean - Cleans up the generated files from the previous build
codesign - Signs the app bundle that was created by xcodebuild
infoplist-modify
keychain-clean - Cleanup the keychain
keychain-create - Create a keychain that is used for signing the app
provisioning-clean
provisioning-install
test - Run the unit test fo the Xcode project
xcodebuild - Builds the Xcode project
```

In your gradle script you can have a default xcodebuild block

```
xcodebuild {
   workspace = 'iPhone.xcworkspace'
   scheme='iPhone'
   configuration='Release' 
   sdk='iphoneos' 
   unitTestTarget='iPhoneTests' 
}
```

Problem: the unitTestTarget won't work because the sdk is not iphonesimulator (see: https://github.com/openbakery/gradle-xcodePlugin)

Note that there is a test task defined for you by the Xcode plugin above. So we add a test block:

```
test {
    xcodebuild {
        sdk='iphonesimulator'
        configuration='Debug'
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still not getting it, like how it is going to solve my build all targets problem?

Comment: If your build targets are for the same application and are targets for test/archive etc. Then you can use the xcodebuild inside the other targets (supplied by the plugin) to override settings from the general configuration of the xcodebuild task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will work, could you try next:

```
task xcodebuild1 (type: XcodeBuildTask) {
    ....
    doFirst {
        project.xcodebuild.scheme = 'MyUnitTestScheme'
    }
    doLast {
        project.xcodebuild.scheme = null // resetting the scheme to default
    }
}

task xcodebuild2 (type: XcodeBuildTask) {
    ....
    doFirst {
        project.xcodebuild.sdk = 'iphoneos'
    }
    doLast {
        project.xcodebuild.sdk = 'iphonesimulator' // resetting the sdk to default
    }
}

task buildAll{
   dependsOn xcodebuild1, xcodebuild2
}
```

Comment: xcode build isn't a task as far as i know and the task declaration of buildAll should just be "task buildAll(dependsOn:[xcodebuild1, xcodebuild2])"

Comment: That what I found: https://github.com/openbakery/gradle-xcodePlugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/groovy/org/openbakery/XcodeBuildTask.groovy

Comment: so you might be able to setup multiple tasks of type XcodeBuildTask. "xcodebuild" is just the action name which is not part of the public api and automatically executed when a task of type XcodeBuildTask is triggered. I've updated your snippet

Comment: Thank you for update! I'm still learning gradle and appreciate help

Comment: What worked for me (at least for just build) was, create a scheme with no targets, add all other targets to the scheme and build the scheme 

It will automatically build all targets in the scheme. However I failed to archive the scheme though.